# How to give two alternate background images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

css code

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(224,224,224,0.6); 
  background: url(../img/backlogo.png),url(../img/backlogo2.png);

}
```

I want to give two background images one after the other alternately.I have shown the output in the [image]. I want the two images repeated one next to other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224, 0.6);
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Acid2.png), url(http://easycarkeys.com/images/accept.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: right center, left center;
  height:250px;
}
```

Ref : **[Using CSS multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)**

---

**UPDATE :** To avoid overflow set background position based the width and height of other background image

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224, 0.6);
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Acid2.png), url(http://easycarkeys.com/images/accept.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position:  200px  center,left center;
  height:250px;
}
```

Comment: i want the repeated image and when i remoce no-repeat property it is overlapping it should be one next to other

Comment: @HarshDesai set `background-position` based on the first image in `px`

Comment: thank you sir i want exactly the same output but it should be repeated one next to other

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like,

```
body {
  background-image: url(sheep.png), url(betweengrassandsky.png);
  background-position: center bottom, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[Multiple Background](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)

Comment: no it is overlapping and i want the background to be repeated because  the images are of the logo size. i have updated the image u can see the result. it is overlapping

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example making multiple background images using css, [CSS3 Backgrounds](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp)

```
#example1 {
  background-image: url(img_flwr.gif), url(paper.gif);
  background-position: right bottom, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works wonders for me:

```
body {
background: url("images/bgInit1C.gif") no-repeat scroll 0px 0% transparent url("images/bgInit1Repeat.gif") repeat-y scroll 0px 0px;
}
```

With this code, the two images overlap, but you can change their x y values for different positioning.

Answer (score 0):

> CSS3 allows this sort of thing and it looks like this:

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/bgtop.png), url(images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
}
```

> The current versions of all the major browsers now support it, however
>   if you need to support IE8 or below, then the best way you can work
>   around it is to have extra divs:

```
<body>
    <div id="bgTopDiv">
        content here
    </div>
</body>

body{
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
}
#bgTopDiv{
    background-image: url(images/bgTop.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: it is repeating only one image i want both the images to be repeated one next to other

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo.

You gotta give `background-position` to stack the background image

```css
body {  
    background:
      url(http://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/y2kT6dH4XBt3hJoTsOeHKA/ls.jpg) no-repeat  top right,
      url(http://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/lcBBwRuHvzHIVI6tors32A/ls.jpg) no-repeat top left;
  }
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#sample1 {
  background-image: url(image/sample1.gif), url(image/samplle2.gif);
  background-position: right bottom, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
}
```